# didCellParse does not return cell

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I'm trying to center a row. My `<td>` has colspan across the table.

I have a data tag in the `<td>` because I have dynamic subheaders in the tables. With `willDrawCell` and `didDrawCell` I can access the `cell.raw` property and check the data tag to apply the style.

When I use `didCellParse` the CellHookData has `cell` as undefined.

With the `willDrawCell` and `didDrawCell`, I can alter the `halign` property, but it DOES NOT render in the center of the row in pdf.

```js
didParseCell: data => {                                  
             if($(data.cell.raw).data('subhead') == true){                 
                 data.cell.halign = 'center';                              
             }                
       }
```

With `didParseCell` I receive an error, because `cell` is undefined.

https://codepen.io/lightningmd/pen/gOOaezM
This code pen is using `willDrawCell`. You can see the subheader is found, and the cell.styles.halign is applied. Just change to `didParseCell` for the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the styles on the cell styles object, not the cell: `data.cell.styles.halign = 'center'`.

Seems there also is a bug where `didParseCell` is called with a null value for `data.cell` when there are colspans/rowspans. All in all, this should work:

```
   didParseCell: data => {   
         if (data.cell && $(data.cell.raw).data('subhead') == true) {  
             console.log('Subheader Found;')
             data.cell.styles.halign = 'center'; 
         }             
   }
```